# Getting error while picking document throguh uidocumentpickerviewcontroller from onedrive ios

Tags: ios, file, onedrive, documents, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am trying to choose document from onedrive using uidocumentpickerviewcontroller in my ios App (ios 10.3.3) , i am getting error "selected file not found " , but it's working fine in ios11 . whats wrong with ios10